# How to Trace and display friend within the specified range on MKMap in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to display a friend on map, when the user logins into the app, he would have to choose the range like (e.g. within 5 Km, 10 Km, or 10 above).

If user selects 5 km, then all friends must be displayed that are within this specified Range.

Need guidance on how to implement this using `MKMapView`. This is some code that I have used :

```
-(void) 5KmRange
 {
     // code for 5 Km Range....
 }

 -(void) 10KmRange
 {
     // code for 10 Km Range....
 }

 -(void) 10AboveKmRange
 {
     // code for 10 above Km Range....
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should find the lat long among 5km. And then add these lat long to your map view.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is more like an idea of which delegate functions to use:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger radius;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKPointAnnotation *currentAnnotation;


- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    if(state == CLRegionStateUnknown){
        NSLog(@"Region Unknown");
    } else if(state == CLRegionStateInside){
        NSLog(@"Region Inside");
    } else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside ){
        NSLog(@"Region Outside");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Region Mystery");
    }

}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    self.currentAnnotation.coordinate = locations.lastObject.coordinate;
}


-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    //Add annotation on Map
}


- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    // Remove annotation
}



-(void) setUpNearbyRegion {
    MKPointAnnotation *referenceAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    referenceAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.628647, 22.948567);
    referenceAnnotation.title=@"Your title”;
    self.nearbyArea = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:referenceAnnotation.coordinate radius:self.radius identifier:@"ReferenceLocationIdentifier"];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:companyAnnotation];
}


-(void) 5KmRange  // This should be invoked by an IBAction
{
    // code for 5 Km Range....
    self.radius = 5;
}

-(void) 10KmRange // This should be invoked by an IBAction
{
    // code for 10 Km Range....
    self.radius = 10;
}


-(void) 10KmRange // This should be invoked by an IBAction
{
    // code for 10 Km Range....
    self.radius = 10;
```